# Predict multiple pictures and save prediction in array

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I'm currently looking for a way to predict multiple picture and save the predicts in an array. My current method is now save all image tensor in an array, iterate through the array and predict every images and save the inputs in array. Is there any way more efficient?

My code for 1 picture prediction

```
def predict_image(path):
    print("Prediction in progress")
    image = Image.open(path)

    transformation = transforms.Compose([
        transforms.CenterCrop(224),
        transforms.ToTensor(),
        transforms.Normalize((0.5, 0.5, 0.5), (0.5, 0.5, 0.5))
    ])

    img_tensor = transformation(image).float()
    img_tensor = img_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)

    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        img_tensor.cuda()

    input = Variable(img_tensor)
    output = model(input)
    index = output.data.numpy().argmax()
    return index
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might be one of the best ways to predict the output at test time.

Another thing you might want to try is to feed the input in a batch-wise manner.
Since you are storing all the tensors in a list, you could use `torch.stack(list)` to stack the multiple tensors in one unique tensor. Then you can just feed it to the model.

Watch out that in this way you must decide apriori what should be the size of the batch and you must pay attention to not exaggerate. PyTorch stores the tensors in the RAM (if you are using the CPU) or in the VRAM (if you are using the GPU), so increasing too much the size of the batch may lead to **`CUDA OOM error`**.